Remove duplicate rows in DataFrame based on one column containing a substring
I have a dataframe like the following:
ID, Components
1,  "Room 1, ABC"
2,  "Room 2, ABC"
3,  "Room 3, DEF"
4,  "Room 1, DEF"
5,  "Room 3, DEF" 


I need to filter the dataframe so that there is only one row per room and the first occurrence of a given room is kept:
ID, Components
1,  "Room 1, ABC"
2,  "Room 2, ABC"
3,  "Room 3, DEF"

As shown above, we can see the rows with ID 4&5 have been removed as "Room 1" and "Room 3" is used in row's with IDs 1 and 3.
Alternatively, a count of unique rooms would also work, however the remainder of the string for Components can repeat, e.g. there can be numerous ABCs and DEFs but only 1 Room 1/2/3...
Therefore counting unique entries in the Components column will not work. It must be unique only for "Room n".

Input data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.arange(1, 6), 'Components': ['Room 1, ABC', 'Room 2, ABC', 'Room 3, DEF', 'Room 1, DEF', 'Room 3, DEF']})

Use str.extract:
df.loc[~df['Components'].str.extract('(\d+)').duplicated()]

Output:
   ID   Components
0   1  Room 1, ABC
1   2  Room 2, ABC
2   3  Room 3, DEF


Will do, only a few points away haha..

Using groupby.first
df.groupby(df["Components"].str.extract(r"^(Room\s+\d+)", 
              expand=False), as_index=False).first()


I believe adding groupby here is a not needed, as it takes up extra processing time.

IIUC, extract the Room id and use duplicated to form a mask for boolean indexing:
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'Components': ['Room 1, ABC',
                                  'Room 2, ABC',
                                  'Room 3, DEF',
                                  'Room 1, DEF',
                                  'Room 3, DEF']})

m = df['Components'].str.extract(r'(Room \d+)', expand=False).duplicated()

out = df[~m]

Output:
   ID   Components
0   1  Room 1, ABC
1   2  Room 2, ABC
2   3  Room 3, DEF

Intermediates:
   ID   Components extract      m     ~m
0   1  Room 1, ABC  Room 1  False   True
1   2  Room 2, ABC  Room 2  False   True
2   3  Room 3, DEF  Room 3  False   True
3   4  Room 1, DEF  Room 1   True  False
4   5  Room 3, DEF  Room 3   True  False


Add a new column for the "rooms" using a regular expression to extract them from "Components":
df["extract"] = df["Components"].str.extract("(.+,)")

Then group the same "rooms" and for every group choose the first item:
df.groupby("extract").first()

If you want to delete the "extract" index:
df.groupby("extract").first().reset_index(drop=True)


First create a dataframe for your data:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

### Extract the room number from the 'Components' column
df['Room'] = df['Components'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0].strip())

### Drop duplicates based on the 'Room' column, keeping the first occurrence
df_filtered = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Room', keep='first')

### Drop the 'Room' column as it's no longer needed
df_filtered = df_filtered.drop(columns=['Room'])

This will provide you the filtered list with room number as the unique key.
